# Unable to delete a record in Sqlite db in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Kind of new in Windows 8 app development, I have this issue on this particular part of code.
My app uses SQLite database, and I can't delete a record using primary key.
I use C# by the way. Here is my snippet where I am unable to delete a record using primary key.

>
>

> case "Ok":
>
> ```
>                  string result = string.Empty;
>
>                 int chapterindex=0;
>                 using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path))
>                 {
>
>
>                     var QuestionQ = (db.Table<Chapter>().Where(
>                         c => c.ChapterName == chapterselected)).Single();
>                     chapterindex = QuestionQ.Index;
>                  //the above query executes fine
>                   //  result = chapterselected;  chapterselected is a string containing >//chapter name.
>
>                     try
>                     {//this one wouldn't
>                         db.Delete<Chapter>(chapterindex);
>
>                     }
>                     catch(Exception ex)
>                     {
>                         pageTitle.Text = ex.ToString();
>                     }
> ```

My MVVM class for chapter is...

```
[Table("Chapter")]
public class Chapter
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string ChapterName { get; set; }
    public int ChapterNo { get; set; }

}
```

I did not declare Index as primary key in the above class because I am using autoincrement for that field in my db.
here is my table
[image]

Everything works fine(insert, select, deleteall,drop table etc...except deleting a single row.)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In SQLite, it is not possible to have an autoincrementing column that is not the primary key.

Comment: my primary key is autoincrementing column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you are using [SQLite-Net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) as your database access layer.

The problem is likely that your class definition of `Chapter` does not match your table (SQL) definition. You are missing the `PrimaryKey` and `AutoIncrement` attributes from your class definition:

```
[Table("Chapter")]
public class Chapter
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string ChapterName { get; set; }
    public int ChapterNo { get; set; }
}
```

SQLite-Net does not currently read the SQL table information, so it does not know which column is the primary key. That is why you are having the problem with deleting.

Unrelated to your specific question, but the `AutoIncrement` attribute is useful for inserting records, as it will cause SQLite-Net to set your class `Index` field to be the same as the SQLite generated value for the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this one for a couple hours until I came across Diederik Krols beautiful post at: [His Blog](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/12/05/Using-SQLite-in-a-Windows-Store-MVVM-App.aspx). In my case I kept pulling an Exception that it could not delete due to no Primary Key... but I had my Primary Key set so looked for an alternative and came across his post.

```
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "APE.db");
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {  
                try
                {
                    // Delete Customer Records
                    db.Execute("DELETE FROM EstimateDetails WHERE EstimateDetailID = ?", YourValue);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   // EXCEPTION HANDLING
                }
            }
```